# Sql query including a unicode character returns wrong result

Tags: sql-server, r, unicode

I have a query like this:

```
 select * from Table where column1='bäb'
```

This query returns a result in SQL Server, but if I write it in RStudio:

```
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select * from Table where column1='bäb")
```

such a query is sent to SQL Server:

```
select * from Table where column1='b„b'
```

then it returns wrong result. What should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: This is a code page conversion issue. However, I can't find any code page where `„` is the same byte value as `ä`, which is odd. Still, code pages are controlled by Collation in SQL Server. I haven't played with R yet, but do you have the ability to change the Collation (or just code page) in R Studio, at least when creating that `dbhandle`?

Comment: @srutzky I dont understand what you mean. Do you have any refrence?

Comment: Kaja: what OS is R running on? That plays a large role in this. And I assume Windows for SQL Server, correct? According to this document -- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf -- you might need to set the `DBMSencoding argument to odbcDriverConnect`.

Comment: Also, if you are not connecting using RODBC, then can you please update the question to show how you are connecting? Thanks. Also include the OS info for both R and SQL Server.

Comment: Why you not use parameters? `select * from Table where column1=@value` (@value is nvarchar)

Comment: @srutzky thank you for your hints. Yes you are right. I use windows for SQL Server and I try to connect with `ODBCDatasource Administrator` I have defined my own DNS to connect to database and in R I have written: `dbhandle<-odbcConnect("MyDSN",uid ='bi_admin',pwd = 'pppp')` Do you know if it is possible to set DBMSencoding in user defined DNS?